# Using VLC media player on my own android app

Tags: java, android

Im making a anime app to watch anime easier (for personal use)

I get video and streaming url from my pc with a basic python script using web scraping

So I want to use VLC or similar player(With gesture controls) on my app

Is there a way to do that

since VLC is opensourced I thought it is possible but I couldnt find any sources

Comment: "Open source" doesn't mean "free to take/modify". Does license *explicitly* states that people can reuse that code as they want?

Comment: As I said, it is just for personal use Im not gonna share it. So I if theres something like that I dont think it will be problem

Comment: @Pshemo actually, that is what open source means, there is an official definition: https://opensource.org/osd Specifically VLC is under the GPL license that guarantees the freedom to study, modify, and distribute the modified version for everyone.

Comment: @mantikafasi Sorry, I am not familiar enough with VLC for Android to give you a real answer, but you should check its AndroidManifest.xml There should be a way to send it a URL via Intent so it will start playing it. If you want to actually embed the player window in you own app, that would be more complicated, and will probably require copying a lot of code, unless they provide some library.

Comment: if you need the source, you can find it here: https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android

Comment: You don't need to modify VLC app, you can just sent the URL to the original app: https://wiki.videolan.org/Android_Player_Intents/#Sample_code Instead of the URI to a local file you can use an streaming URI.

Comment: @LevM. Thanks, learned something new today.

Comment: @LevM. But can I have follow up question? One of my teachers (many ears ago) stated that some open-source licenses force applications which use them to also be open-source *and free* (which is why at that time devs who wanted to sell their product didn't want to use them). Since I am not professional dev (nor lawyer) I never had a need to check if that is true. Can you confirm or deny it (since that was main reason of my previous comment - in sense that after using open-source code we can't be sure that our application is not restricted by some obligations and it should be explicitly stated)?

Comment: @Pshemo this is technically against SO rules, to ask an unrelated question in comments on someone else's question. Also, licensing questions do not belong on SO. But, I will give you a short answer and hope the moderators forgive me: your teacher was talking about something called "copyleft": https://www.gnu.org/licenses/copyleft.en.html Some licenses like GPL require that derivitive works will be published under the same license (i.e. give code) others like Apache allow to change license (i.e. close the code). All licenses allow you to sell the app (you can sell with code if needed).

Comment: @LevM. Thank you again.